# Style layer on server side or client side?

Tags: geoserver, sld, css

I have GeoServer installed where I am planning to place our company layers. Since we are using a web front end (Leaflet) to get data onclick (GetFeatureInfo) from some WMS layers should I style the GetFeatureInfo response on server side or client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I style the GetFeatureInfo response on server side or client side?

A GetFeatureInfo response is not styled.

The WMS layers are styled, and the request to get the map image of the WMS layer (or layers) is a GetMap operation.  WMS layers must have some default styling, and can have multiple styles.

A WMS layer can also be styled through an external style sent or referenced in the GetMap request.